Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0 when i run Main.main()
When I ran with --stack-trace, I got this error message.

Execution failed for task ':Main.main()'. > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1  *
Try:
\> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
\> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':Main.main()'.
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 1s 2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date

here's my build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
project.ext.lwjglVersion = "3.3.3"
project.ext.jomlVersion = "1.10.5"
project.ext.lwjglNatives = "natives-windows"



dependencies {
    implementation platform("org.lwjgl:lwjgl-bom:$lwjglVersion")

    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-assimp"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-nfd"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl"
    implementation "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-assimp::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-glfw::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-nfd::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-openal::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-opengl::$lwjglNatives"
    runtimeOnly "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-stb::$lwjglNatives"
    implementation "org.joml:joml:${jomlVersion}"
}

But when I build, it runs successfully.

$ ./gradlew build
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
<-------------> 0% WAITING
\> IDLE


Your main problem is nothing to do with Gradle. You can live with the deprecated features for now.
The key line is
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This shows there is an error from the executing code of your main Java program, not the Gradle program. The error would normally be output to your console before the output you've shared. If not you'll need to investigate why your Java program is not doing so.

thanks for the answer, I solved this problem by changing the intellij idea configuration
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69099077/20656724
